# Time Rescheduling Logic

Tags: php, datetime, time, scheduler

I am working on a scheduler-like code (in PHP if that matters) and encountered an interesting thing: it's easy to reschedule a recurring task, but what if, for some reason, it was run significantly later, than it was supposed to?
For example, let's say a job needs to run every hour and it's next scheduled run is `13.05.2021 18:00`, but it runs at `13.05.2021 20:00`. Now normal rescheduling logic will be taking the original scheduled time and adding recurrence frequency (1 hour in this case), but that would make the new time `13.05.2021 19:00`, which can cause to run this job twice. We could, theoretically, use the time for "last run" but it can be something like `13.05.2021 20:03`, which would make new time `13.05.2021 21:03`.
Now my question is: what logic can we use so that in this case next time would be `13.05.2021 21:00`? I've tried googling something like this, but was not able to find anything. And I do see, that Event Scheduler in Windows, for example, does reschedule jobs in a way, that I want to do that.

Comment: You could drop the minutes to the nearest hour...before re setting the schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a pretty easy way to do what I needed, so posting it as an answer.
If we have a value of `frequency` in seconds (in my case, at least) and we have the original `nextrun`, which is when a task was supposed to be run initially, then the logic is as follows:

1. We need to get current time (`time()`, `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` or whatever).
2. We need to compare current time against `nextrun` and get the difference between them in seconds.
3. We then calculate how many iterations of the task could have been completed in the amount of those seconds by dividing the time difference by `frequency`.
4. We round up the resulting value (`ceil()`). If we have a value lower than 1, we may want to sanitize it.
5. We multiply this rounded up value by `frequency`, which will give us a different result than on step 2, which is the salt of this method.
6. We add the resulting number of seconds to `nextrun`.

And that's it. This does not guarantee, that you won't ever have a task run twice, if it ended just a few seconds before the time value on step 6, but to my knowledge MS Event Scheduler has the same "flaw".
Since I am doing this calculation in SQL, here's how this would look in SQL (at least for MySQL/MariaDB):

```sql
UPDATE `cron__schedule` SET `nextrun`=TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, IF(CEIL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `nextrun`, UTC_TIMESTAMP())/`frequency`) > 0, CEIL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `nextrun`, UTC_TIMESTAMP())/`frequency`), 1)*`frequency`, `nextrun`)
```

To explain by referencing the logic above:

1. `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`
2. `` TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `nextrun`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) `` - time comparison in seconds.
3. `` TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)/`frequency` ``
4. `CEIL(...)` to round up the value. `IF(...)` is used to sanitize, since we can get 0 seconds, that will result in us not changing the time, at all.
5. `` CEIL(...)*`frequency` ``
6. `TIMESTAMPADD(...)`

I do not like having to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)` twice because of `IF(...)`, but I do not know a way to avoid that without moving to a stored procedure, which feels like an overkill. Besides, as far as I know, MySQL should calculate this value only once regardless. But, if someone can advise me on a cleaner approach, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right or wrong in this situation, it really depends on your business logic and how you want to build this.

WordPress and Drupal, two of the largest CMSs out there have faced this problem, too, which boils down to "poor man's cron" versus "system cron". For a "poor man's cron", these systems rely on someone hitting the website in order to "wake" the scheduler up, and if no one visits your site in a month, your tasks don't run, either. Both of these systems instead recommend using the system's cron to be more consistent and "wake up" the scheduler at certain intervals. I would encourage you to explore this in your system, too.

The next problem is, how are you storing your recurrence? Do you have (effectively) a table with every possible run time? So for an hourly run there's 24 entries? Or is there just a single task that has an ideal run date/time? The latter is generally easier to control compared to the former which has a lot of duplicated data being stored.

Then, do tasks reschedule themselves, does the scheduler do that, or is there a middle ground where the scheduler *asks* the task for the next best run? Figuring this out is very important and there's some nuances.

Another thing to think about, what happens if a task runs earlier than planned? For instance, *does the world break* if a task runs as 01:00 and 01:15, or is it just sub-optimal.

Generally when I build these types of systems, my tasks conform to a pattern (interface in OOP) and support a "next run time". The scheduler pulls all of the tasks from a data store that have an expired "next run time" and runs them. Doing this, there's no chance for a single task to exist at both 01:00 and 02:00 because it will only exist in the data store once, for instance at 01:00. If the scheduler then wakes up at 01:15, it finds the 01:00 task which has expired and runs it, and then it asks the task for the next run. The task looks at the clock (or time as provided by the scheduler if you are running in a distributed environment) and the task performs its own logic to determine that. If the logic is every hour, you can add 60 minutes from "now" and then remove the minutes portions, so 01:15 becomes 02:00.

Throw some exception handling and possibly database transactions into this mix to guarantee that a task can't fail but still get rescheduled, too.

Comment: What I'm coding is something is a database stored CRON, in a sense. I have a table of tasks (functions), that allow sending them arguments. They are scheduled in a separate table, with `schedule` value in seconds, that corresponds to frequency the task needs to run. Initial `nextrun` time is set on registration (defaults to current time). A separate job (can be a normal CRON one) gets the list of tasks with time <= current and runs them in succession. After a run, each task is rescheduled by the same job (centralized logic).

Comment: This means, that tasks can't run earlier, but they can, objectively, run later, than planned. Since I allow not only hourly, but even "every several minutes" or "every several seconds" , removing just minutes is not an option, unless I branch out the logic based on the frequency set for a job. Besides, I am not sure I understand how dropping minutes from 01:15 will turn it into 02:00
This is a work in progress but, perhaps, this can help get an idea of what I am going for: https://github.com/Simbiat/Cron

Comment: For the last part, I was saying that a task with two time-based constraints, hourly and on the hour, can be solved by taking the current clock time, adding 60 minutes and then dropping the minute portion. So for a 01:00 task that runs at 01:15 you add 60 minutes and get 02:15, then drop the minutes to get 02:00.

Comment: I see. That would work. But what if the task is to run every 2 minutes, for example?